# Jquery Find - Visible only

Tags: jquery

I want to check if the div contains a children with class "error" but with the condition that the error class display is not equal to none. (Meaning error class must be visible.

How can change my code below:

```
 $(".related_field").each(function(){
     var $widthAdj = $(this).find(".autoDiv");
     if($(this).find(".error").length == 0){  //MUST BE VISIBLE "ERROR" CLASS ONLY
        $widthAdj.css("height","48px");
     } else {
        $widthAdj.css("height","63px");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

You mean like this? Using the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
if($(this).find(".error:visible").length == 0)
    $widthAdj.css("height","48px");
} else {
    $widthAdj.css("height","63px");
}
```